# Error when using \BC (from abbrevs) in \caption

Tags: captions, acronyms

I'm using the `abbrevs` package to provide nicer formatting of BC/AD in dates, but when I use one of the commands in a `caption` I get an error. Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abbrevs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{1500--1000 \BC.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
```

Removing the `\BC` eliminates the error, which leads me to think the problem is in the combination of the two... so how can I use an abbreviation in a caption? Alternatively, is there a better package for formatting BC/AD in dates?

Comment: Such an error almost always means: "you have a fragile command in a moving argument", in this case the argument to `\caption`. Use `\protect\BC`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the commands defined by `abbrevs` are fragile; for example, `\BC` expands to `\DateMark {b.c}` and, in turn, the definition of `\DateMark` is

```
\newcommand\DateMark [1] {%
  \hspace{.2em}{\DateMarkSize\scshape #1}%
  \@ifnextchar. {%
      \spacefactor\@m
    }{% ELSE
    .\maybe@ic@space
  }%
}
```

Any command with `\@ifnextchar` in its definition is fragile, so it needs to be "protected" when in a moving argument.

Solutions:

1. Easy, if you don't have too many of these commands in moving arguments

   ```
   \caption{1500--1000 \protect\BC.}
   ```
2. Safer, if you don't want to bother with all these `\protect`

   ```
   \usepackage{abbrevs}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   \robustify{\DateMark} % after having loaded abbrevs
   ```

   It's better to robustify `\DateMark` rather than `\BC`, as this covers all date abbreviations.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks. I went with option 2 as that seemed cleaner.